# Music Library Sorting Issue

Tags: music, windows-media-player, sorting

I'm using WMP for for managing my music library. Lately I noticed something. I was reorganizing my library and came across a strange -I mean annoying- behavior of WMP. The way WMP sorts Artists.

Normally it sorts them next to each other like a line, and when there's no space it moves to next line, a unit below, then continues to sorting. You know what I'm talking about. This goes on until you reach the 25th artist. If there's a 25th artist sorting changes. It won't sort artists next to each other but group them with letters and sort to below. I don't want that.

I did some googling and found out that I'm not the only one who's annoyed with this. And as a solution, people suggested using WMP Plus!. So I downloaded and tested. It solves the problem. Kinda. It removes the -letter- headers. So it goes back to default sorting. But then things get messy. There's no line separator between albums. So I have to resize album covers column to put some space between them. Troublesome.

Is there a better way to fix this? Or does anyone know if this behavior is intentionally put? If so, it sucks.

While writing this, I noticed not just artist sorting but also other sorting methods does the same thing. Album, genre... After the 25th item it starts annoying.

EDIT: using WMP 12.

Comment: so you googled it, found the answer, and now you want an alternate answer? I could be wrong, but I really doubt anyone is going to have a fix for such a minor pet peeve such as this.

Comment: Hmm. I think that depends on the definition of answer. If I asked you 2+2, you could say 4, or 2^2, or sqrt(16). These are more like a workaround. I think. Anyway. I like to try my luck. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @ Akinuri : Which windows version are you using?

Comment: This answer can help you : http://superuser.com/questions/172616/how-can-i-configure-windows-media-player-to-manage-my-music-library

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the WMP Plus! plug-in. What exactly do you mean with there being no line separator between albums and having to resize the album covers column? A screenshot would be helpful here.

Comment: [default](http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/default.jpg),  [after plus](http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/afterplus.jpg),  [after plus with column resize](http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/afterplusandcolumnresize.jpg)

I get the desired result with artist sorting but I want to keep the headers on album sorting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a way yet for WMP Plus! to determine the current view in the library, so there's currently no other possibility than to make the library header setting 'all or nothing'. I might change this if I ever do find a way.

Comment: Btw, I thought I should clarify. I was talking about the WMP's sorting behavior -that it changes if there's an 25th item- when I said "if the behavior is intentionally put, it sucks". Also if there was an option to remove headers for each sorting methods -artist, album, genre etc- it'd be awesome. Hope you get the time and a way to do that.